# How to retrive property values from array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
[{
    "circlemarker": [{
        "type": "circle_marker"
    }, {
        "latlong": "abc"
    }]
}, {
    "connector_marker": [{
        "type": "icon_marker"
    }, {
        "latlong": "pqr"
    }]
}, {
    "icon_marker": [{
        "type": "connector_marker"
    }, {
        "latlong": "xyz"
    }]
}]
```

I want to access `latlong` values of each marker. So how can I have access to each property in this structure.

Comment: Is your data really structured like that? Does it **need** to be? That's the first thing I'd change, that looks like it would be a huge headache to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get latlong data:

```
for (var a = 0; a < obj.length; a++) {
    var key = Object.keys(obj[a])[0];
    var latlong = obj[a][key][1];
    console.log(latlong));
}
```

But i think that data have not correct structure, this is better solution:

```
var markers = [{
    "name": "circlemarker",
    "type": "circle_marker"
    "latlong": "abc"
}, {
    "name": "connector_marker",
    "type": "icon_marker",
    "latlong": "pqr"
}, {
    "name": "icon_marker",
    "type": "connector_marker",
    "latlong": "xyz"
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you:-

```
var makers = [{"circlemarker":[{"type":"circle_marker"},{"latlong":"abc"}]},{"connector_marker":[{"type":"icon_marker"},{"latlong":"pqr"}]},{"icon_marker":[{"type":"connector_marker"},{"latlong":"xyz"}]}];
makers.forEach(function(maker){
    var makerName = Object.keys(maker)[0];
    console.log(maker[makerName][1]["latlong"]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

so for each object in the array, you want to pluck the `latlong` from the first key which also references another array of objects. Man I would fix this data structure but if you can't control it, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var data = [{
    "circlemarker": [{
        "type": "circle_marker"
    }, {
        "latlong": "abc"
    }]
}, {
    "connector_marker": [{
        "type": "icon_marker"
    }, {
        "latlong": "pqr"
    }]
}, {
    "icon_marker": [{
        "type": "connector_marker"
    }, {
        "latlong": "xyz"
    }]
}];

var _ = require('lodash')
, coords = [];

_.each(data, function(item){
  //console.log(item);

  var key = _(Object.keys(item)).first()
    , first = item[key]
    , latLong = _.pluck(first, 'latlong')[1];

  if ( latLong ) {
     coords.push(latLong);
  }

});

console.log(coords);
```

Produces the following output:

```
[ 'abc', 'pqr', 'xyz' ]
```

Comment: Is valid solution, but with nodejs.

Comment: uses lodash or underscore, it works fine anywhere :)

Comment: yes, but require is a nodejs method, unless you use requirejs :)

Comment: you would skip the `var _ = require('lodash')` and load `<script src=/path/to/lodash.js>`